# Perl Directory Walking issue - Can't go back up more than 1 directory properly

Tags: perl, search, directory

First off, I don't have the ability to use File::Find.

So I have my script to walk through directories and find a certain type of file.  But if I go more than one sub-directory deep, my script doesn't properly exit all the way back up to the starting directory.  I think I need to have a $previousDir variable that keeps track of the last directory so I can say to go back out to that one when I'm done in the sub-directory.  But I've tried putting it in multiple places without success...

File Structure (**BOLD** is a Dir, *Italic* is a file):

startingdirectory/Logs - **AAA**, **Dir1**, **zzz**, *adstatlog.299, adstatlog.tgz, file*

/**AAA** - *filefile*

/**Dir1** - /**Dir2**, *config.tar.gz*

/**Dir2** - EMPTY

/**zzz** - *withinzzz*

Here is my current script:

```
# specify the directory where you want to start the search
my $startingDir = $ARGV[0];
my $directoryCount = 0;
my $directory = shift;
my $previousDir;
my @directories;
my $tarOutput;

# Calling the Subroutine, which searches the Directory
readDirectory($startingDir);

sub readDirectory
{
    # Open and close the startingDir
    opendir(DIR, @_[0]) or die("ERROR: Couldn't open specified directory $!");
    my @files = grep { $_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir DIR;
    closedir DIR;

    print "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    foreach my $currentFile (@files)
    {   
        print "Current File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";

        #Directory currently searching through
        print "Searching in $directory\n\n";

        my $fullPath = "$directory/$currentFile";
        print "FULL PATH: $fullPath\n\n";
        if ( -d $fullPath )
        {
            print "Found New Directory: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
            push (@directories, $currentFile);
            $directoryCount++;
            print "Current number = $directoryCount\n\n";
            print "Directories: @directories \n\n";
            $previousDir = $directory;
            $directory = $fullPath;
            # The Subroutine is calling hisself with the new parameters
            readDirectory($directory);
        }

        elsif ( $currentFile =~ /\.tar.gz$/i || $currentFile =~ /\.tar$/i || $currentFile =~ /\.tgz$/i)
        {
            print "File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
            my $tarOutput = `tar -tvzf $currentFile`;
            print $tarOutput, "\n";
            $previousDir = $directory;
        }

        print "PREVIOUSDIR: $previousDir\n\n";

        print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

        $directory = $previousDir;
    }   
}
```

And the output: (scroll down to see where issue begins)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: AAA

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

Found New Directory: AAA

Current number = 1

Directories: AAA

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: filefile

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/filefile

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs

 ------------------------------------------------------------------

 PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs

 ------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: Dir1

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

Found New Directory: Dir1

Current number = 2

Directories: AAA Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: DIR2

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/DIR2

Found New Directory: DIR2

Current number = 3

Directories: AAA Dir1 DIR2

------------------------------------------------------------------------

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: configs.tar.gz

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/configs.tar.gz

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1  ***THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE STARTS - 
                                          PREVIOUSDIR SHOULD BE /Logs!!***

------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: file

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/file

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: adstatlog.299

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/adstatlog.299

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: zzz

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/zzz

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: adstatlog.tgz

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1/adstatlog.tgz

PREVIOUSDIR: /home/gackerma/Logs/Dir1

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that you don't have the ability to use `File::Find` but you think you have the ability to re-implement it. Your time could have been better spent learning the module. There is a `find2perl` command that will generate `File::Find` code from unix `find` syntax and give you a better idea on how to use it.

Comment: well, actually, apparently I can.  co-worker is getting the module installed on the backup server, which I didn't have access to.

I still wish I knew how to do it manually.....

Comment: It's a core module, it shouldn't need to be installed unless you are on an ancient version of perl.

Comment: Welllllll when I try to just include it in the script I get:

Can't locate File/Find/Rule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at tarSearch.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tarSearch.pl line 4.

Comment: That's because `File::Find::Rule` isn't a core module. [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is great, and easy to use. You should try it.

Comment: Oh...GAHHHHH that explains it...

Comment: @user215654 you should have a play with `File::Find` at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really use `File::Find` if you can.

Here's a working, simplified version of your recursive try:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 (abs path to dir) " if @ARGV != 1;

my $dir = shift @ARGV;

file_find($dir);

sub file_find {
    my $dir = shift;

    opendir my $dh, $dir or warn "$dir: $!";
    my @files = grep { $_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir $dh;
    closedir $dh;

    for my $file ( @files ) { 
        my $path = "$dir/$file";

        if( $path =~ /(\.tar\.gz|\.tar|\.tgz)$/ ) { 
            print "do tar for $path\n";
        }   
        file_find($path) if -d $path;
    }   
}
```

Comment: and that seems to have worked!! thank you so much!!! 

I've been trying to use File::Find::Rule (even though I mentioned File::Find in my post...)

Answer (score 0):

The `File::Find` module has been a standard Unix module since Perl 5.000. In fact, it's been a standard module since Perl 3.x, maybe even before. In fact, I have Perl 5.12 installed on my Mac, and I still see the old `find.pl` file sitting in one of the `@INC` directories.

Back before Perl 5 (or maybe even before Perl 4), you'd do this:

```
require "find.pl";
```

instead of

```
use File::Find;
```

TO get the `find` command on your system (`find.pl` is there for backwards compatibility). This is why I find it so hard to believe you don't have `File::Find` on your system. It'd be like saying you don't have the `dir` command on your Windows PC.

Run the command `perl -V`. That's a capital `V`. This will print out the `@INC` directory list. See if you can find a `File` directory in only of those directories listed in that list. Under that directory should be a `Find.pm` Perl module.

Here's what it looks like on my PC running Strawberry Perl:

```
@INC:
  C:/perl/perl/site/lib
  C:/perl/perl/vendor/lib
  C:/perl/perl/lib
  .
```

On my Mac, 10 directories are listed in that `@INC` list.

Also see which version of Perl you have on your system. And, make sure the directories listed in `@INC` are readable by you.

There is something definitely wrong with your Perl installation if you don't have `File::Find` on your system. I'd be more worried about that than `File::Find` itself.

One more thing, see if you have `perldoc` command installed. If you do, type:

```
$ perldoc File::Find
```

and see if that gives you any documentation on File::Find. If it does, it means that File::Find is on your system. Then run:

```
$ perldoc -l File::Find
```

which will give you the location of the File::Find module.

Before doing anything else, verify that File::Find really, really doesn't exist on your system, or that you don't have read access to it before doing anything else. As I said before, if this module doesn't exist on your system, you have major problems with your Perl installation, and I'd be worried whether it can be trusted. This needs to be resolved.

If everything is okay, then we need to see your program to figure out why you can't use `File::Find`. It might be something minor, like using quotes around the program's name.

Comment: thank you so much for all of the info!  I'm actually just a moron and, while mentioning File::find in my post, I've been trying to get File::Find::Rule to work.  A previous poster posted a script using File::Find and it does indeed work.  

Despite my dumbness, that was all very useful info that you provided and I thank you again :)

Comment: `File::Find::Rule` is a bit different. I'm not thrilled with that module. You end up with so many different rules, it's just easier to program it yourself. `File::Find::Object` is better. You can take a look at my [File::OFind](https://github.com/qazwart/File-OFind). You can install the `Find` directory tree (under `lib`) in the same directory as your program. If nothing else, take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your program. The main error is that you are using too many global variables and trying to manually keep them in synch with the directory you are currently processing.

Here is a list

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` for every program you write
- `warnings` would have told you that you should write `opendir(DIR, $_[0])` instead of `opendir(DIR, @_[0])`
- You are setting `$directory` to `$previousDir` after every entry in a directory. But `$previousDir` is being set only when the current entry is another directory, so after ordinary files the value is restored even though it hasn't been saved.
- You are getting confused about whether you should be reading the directory specified by global variable `$directory` or by the parameter passed to the subroutine.

By far the easiest way to do this is to use *only* the subroutine parameter to specify the current directory and forget about the global variable. Here is a program that does what yours is intended to

```
use strict;
use warnings;

process_dir($ARGV[0]);

sub process_dir {

  my ($dir) = @_;

  opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;
  my @entries = grep { not /^\.\.?$/ } readdir $dh;
  closedir $dh;

  for my $entry (@entries) {
    my $fullname = "$dir/$entry";
    if (-d $fullname) {
      process_dir($fullname);
    }
    elsif ($entry=~ /(?:\.tar|\.tgz|\.tar\.gz)$/i)
      print "File: ", $fullname, "\n\n";
      print `tar -tvzf $fullname`;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question.  I really wanted to know how to do it manually even though I now know that File::Find works.  And yours works as well!! :)